# Internal messaging in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, messaging

I'm using this tutorial to get internal messages working on my site: http://www.novawave.net/public/rails_messaging_tutorial.html

But, since my latest upgrade to Rails 3, I'm getting this error:

```
NoMethodError in MsgController#sendmsg
undefined method `each' for #<String:0xcc8acc0>
```

Application trace:

```
app/models/message.rb:16:in `prepare_copies'
app/controllers/msg_controller.rb:140:in `sendmsg'
```

The Message model:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, :class_name => "User"
  has_many :message_copies
  has_many :recipients, :through => :message_copies
  before_create :prepare_copies

  attr_accessor  :to # array of people to send to
  attr_accessible :subject, :body, :to

  def prepare_copies
    return if to.blank?

    to.each do |recipient|
      recipient = User.find(recipient)
      message_copies.build(:recipient_id => recipient.id, :folder_id => recipient.inbox.id)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: We need your controller msg_controller because it's in their the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That tutorial seems a bit dated. It uses Rails 2.0 (and probably some equally old Ruby version).

Are you sure that `to` holds an Array (as indicated in your `attr_accessor` comment)? The error message seems to indicate that it is a String.

Did you previously have this code running under Ruby 1.8 (and, presumably, a version of Rails 2.3)?

In Ruby 1.8 you could send `each` to String instances and it would (by default) iterate on the lines of the string (actually it would split on `$/` and iterate on the result).

In Ruby 1.9 you need to use `each_line` to iterate over the lines of a string.

```
to.each_line do |recipient|
  …
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you to is no anymore an Array but a String now. You problem semmes becomes from your controller and how you define your to accessor inside it.